# GroceryCRUD : How to set field dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, grocery-crud

I just code with GroceryCRUD,
This is my Database:

> **a_guest_data**

```
guest_no
register_date 
name 
gender 
birthday 
address 
city 
country 
phone 
email 
ref 
status 
date_modified
```

> **a_table_data**

```
id_table 
tbl_name 
group_name 
status 
seat 
party_date 
locked 
pos_tbl 
date_modified
```

> **a_table_group**

```
id_table 
guest_no 
priority
```

This is my Code for the Controller:

```
public function guest_management()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_table('a_guest_data');
    $crud->set_subject('Guest');
    $crud->set_relation_n_n('tables', 'a_table_group', 'a_table_data', 'guest_no', 'id_table', 'tbl_name');
    $crud->unset_columns('register_date','layout_no', 'date_modified', 'ref');

    $crud->fields('name', 'register_date', 'gender', 'birthday', 'tables', 'address', 'city', 'country', 'phone', 'email', 'ref', 'status' );


    $crud->field_type('country','dropdown', array('Indonesia' => 'Indonesia', 'Others' => 'Others'));
    $crud->field_type('gender','dropdown', array('Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'));
    $crud->field_type('status','dropdown', array('1' => '1', '2' => '2'));

    $output = $crud->render();

    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

And I have the form like this
[image]
[image]

In the field Tables, I want to set the dropdown fields that only can choose 1 table (The Fact is, now in the field Tables, I can choose many options table. *See in the picture, I choose Table 1, 45, 6, 34).

How can I do that?

Comment: What are you using as a dropdown? Please post that code.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is due to your database structure. If you only want one table value you need your database structure to be "*1-n database relation*"

[image: 1-n database relation]

[Documentation for about database relationships](https://condor.depaul.edu/gandrus/240IT/accesspages/relationships.htm)

What you want to achieve in grocery crud terms is set_relation.

Syntax for `set_relation`:

```php
void set_relation( string $field_name , string  $related_table, string $related_title_field  [, mixed $where [, string $order_by ] ] )
```

[Docs for set_relation](https://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation/)

In the end your `priority` field will also be in the table `a_guest_data`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a multiple select input, try removing MULTIPLE markup.
It depends on what type of select you are using.